# Minimize keystrokes tag

Tags: discussion, tags

I think we should have a tag e.g. [minimize-keystrokes](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minimize-keystrokes) for questions that are about doing a particular task in as few keystrokes as possible.

- [Faster way to move a block of text](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/598/faster-way-to-move-a-block-of-text)
- [Move vertically to a specific character on a different line](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/528/move-vertically-to-a-specific-character-on-a-different-line)
- [How to paste and remove current line](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/442/how-to-paste-and-remove-current-line)
- [Expand a visual selection in the other direction](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/431/expand-a-visual-selection-in-the-other-direction)

All of these questions are about doing a particular task in as few keystrokes as possible, the author clearly knows *at least one way* to do a task, what they are asking is "how can I do this with fewer keystrokes"?

This tag is equivalent to tags like [user-interface](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/user-interface), [validation](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/validation), and [performance](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performance) on StackOverflow... not about a particular technology, but about a category of question that spans many different technologies.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are vimgolf questions on-topic?](http://meta.vi.stackexchange.com/questions/92/are-vimgolf-questions-on-topic)

Comment: I don't see how this is *usefully* different than a "golf" question, at least terms of needing a tag for it. I'd also contend some of those examples you cited as being about "fewest characters possible," since many of them simply say "easiest" (which is not *always the same* as fewest).

Comment: This is definitely not about vimgolf, it's about minimizing keystrokes for common tasks

Comment: I agree this is not about Vimgolf, but rather about going about your every-day Vim life in a more efficient way. However, I don't see how this tag is useful. Can anyone be an expert in minimizing keystrokes? This is different from user-interface & performance, in which you can be an expert. Validation is also not a particularly useful tag, IMHO.

Comment: You're right, it's related, but the actual question isn't a duplicate. I still don't think this kind of tag is worthwhile though.

Answer (score 7):

Efficiency would be assumed to be a desirable attribute for answers even if the question didn't mention anything about keystrokes.  Such a tag would could be applicable to nearly every question and therefore meaningless.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think such a tag is useful in any way. Tags are for classification of questions and searchability. [minimize-keystrokes](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minimize-keystrokes) would only be useful to modify another tag, and is more about the *answer* than the question.